# Mail(smtp) wrong credentials in .env mail settings still mail is sent

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I wanted to check if the mail service I am using is working or not. So, I changed my username and password wrong in .env file. Still, Mails are sent from my site. My .env file looks like this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=secret
MAIL_PASSWORD=212232
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

I want to know how that is possible.

Comment: check your config mail.php

Comment: In config/mail.php , I am using env variables @KuldeepMishra

Comment: try `php artisan cache:clear` & `php artisan view:clear`. afterwards restart the queue you are using for sending mails. This should do it.

Comment: I tried that, too. @parthu_panther

Comment: check your config/mail.php is it using env variables?

like "host" => env('HOST','mailgun')  [USING env() helper function ]

if don't it will definitely won't use env value 

or it is using env helper it may be the cache issue try to run this command 

'php artisan config:cache'

Comment: If your `APP_ENV=production` or you cached the config manually, you need to clear the config cache any time you make changes to your .env file: `php artisan config:clear` (or config:cache, which will clear and then re-cache). Also, if mails are being queued instead of immediately sent, you need to re-start that background queue listener process.